# fancyhdr and long header on first page

Tags: fancyhdr

I am trying to create a document with `fancyhdr` and a pretty long header. It works on all pages except the first page, where the text flows into the header. On the following pages the text starts after the header is finished.

Why doesn't the text get bumped down by the header? What is different about the first page and how can I fix this?

Here is a simple test case showing my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\fancyhf{}

\chead{
  I am a header \\
  with multiple lines \\
  many lines \\
  many many lines \\
  many many many lines
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\blindtext[30]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Off-topic: Please replace `german` by `ngerman`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That is, unless you want to write a document following the old orthographic rules (pre-1996, I suppose).

Comment: @moewe: Yes, true, and I would like to use the old rules too, but unfortunately, I am a teacher at a German school and have to use the new rules :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console compilation of the original document from the O.P shows a clear warning:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 58.54448pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

That's why `\headheight` has to be changed, to at least `59pt`, which less than `1in`, I've used `3cm` here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{3cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\fancyhf{}

\chead{
  I am a header \\
  with multiple lines \\
  many lines \\
  many many lines \\
  many many many lines
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\blindtext[30]
\end{document}
```

[image]