# larger header on first page

Tags: fancyhdr

I have a multipage document that has a larger header on the first page. However, it is not a titlepage, I don't know where it ends. I would like the pagebreaks to be determined automatically. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267524/fancyhdr-and-long-header-on-first-page) is almost solving my problem. For a better view I would like to shift downwards the header on the first page a little. This means also the textheight is decreased for this page. But by increasing the top parameter the textheight isn't adjusted and the footer disappears from the page. 
There are quite some questions on this issue but I just can't find the one solving my problem. Here is my code so far.

Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe,left=25mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm,top=32mm,headheight=14.0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[C]{all but 1st page}
\fancyfoot[L]{leftfooter} 
\fancyfoot[R]{rightfooter}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
\newgeometry{left=25mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm,top=32mm,headheight=66.0pt}
\chead{1st page\\1st page\\1st page\\1st page\\1st page}
\lfoot{leftfooter}
\rfoot{rightfooter}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure this is what you need, but I propose a solution which works with your example and doesn't require using `\newgeometry`. I took the opportunity to simplify setting the page parameters for geometry.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[showframe, margin=25mm, top=32mm, headheight=14.0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[C]{all but 1st page}
\fancyfoot[L]{leftfooter}
\fancyfoot[R]{rightfooter}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
\chead{\smash{\raisebox{0.4\height}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering 1st page\\1st page\\1st page\\1st page\\1st page}}}}
\lfoot{leftfooter}
\rfoot{rightfooter}
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\leavevmode \vspace{6ex}     

\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am afraid I don't see the difference.
However, using your approach I can easily set the first page's header as I wish by playing with the top and the headheight parameter. But from the second page on the headers don't need to be that big in height. So, I would like to have a smaller top parameter from page 2 on.

Comment: The probelm is that `\newgeometry` starts a new page. My code uses the same parameters for the page as all other pages, but neutralises the warning message about  headheight, just smashing the header content.  How much it goes under the header base line depends on the argument given to `\raisebox`. You can have some empty lines at the beginning of the first page, and it won't matter if the header overflows into these empty lines

Comment: I've slightly modified the code. Is it something like this that  you're after?